# How to access newtype named tuples fields in haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples, named, newtype

I declare the following newtypes:

```
newtype Code = Code String deriving (Show)
newtype Name = Name String deriving (Show)
newtype Account = Account (Code, Name) deriving (Show)
```

So:

```
*Main Lib> :t Code
Code :: String -> Code
*Main Lib> :t Name
Name :: String -> Name
*Main Lib> :t Account
Account :: (Code, Name) -> Account
```

and then I create some instances:

```
cn = Code "1.1.1"
nn = Name "Land And Buildings"
an = Account (cn, nn)

*Main Lib> an
Account (Code "1.1.1",Name "Land And Buildings")
```

Now I need to access for example just the `Code` field from the variable `an`, something like `an.Code` How can I do that?

Is it better to use `Data` instead of a `newtype`? If Haskell lets me create a newtype named tuple, then I guess there should be an easy way to access the elements inside.

Comment: `data Account = Account { accCode :: Code, accName :: Name }` and then `accCode an` (NB: a 'named tuple' is a record.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it better to use `data` instead of a `newtype`?

Um, yes... the whole point of `newtype` is to give a *single* type a new name. It's not supposed to be used for building composite types. So, like user2407038 suggested, make it

```
data Account = Account
    { accCode :: Code
    , accName :: Name
    } deriving (Show)
```

and then you can simply use

```
*Main Lib> let an = Account (Code "1.1.1") (Name "Land And Buildings")
*Main Lib> accCode an
Code "1.1.1"
```

That said, it's also not difficult to access fields in a tuple buried in a newtype, provided you give the newtype an unwrapper:

```
newtype Account = Account {getAccount :: (Code, Name)}
   deriving (Show)
```

then

```
*Main Lib> let an = Account (Code "1.1.1", Name "Land And Buildings")
*Main Lib> fst $ getAccount an
Code "1.1.1"
```

---

If you want to be fancy, you can also use the “20.2nd century record accessors”, [lenses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/microlens-platform):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, FunctionalDependencies #-}
import Lens.Micro
import Lens.Micro.TH

data Account = Account
    { accountCode :: Code
    , accountName :: Name
    } deriving (Show)
makeFields ''Account
```

then

```
*Main Lib> let an = Account (Code "1.1.1") (Name "Land And Buildings")
*Main Lib> an^.code
Code "1.1.1"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use pattern matching. E.g.

```
case an of
  Account (Code c, Name n) -> "Code " ++ c ++ ", Name " ++ n
```

or, in a function definition you can directly write

```
foo :: Account -> String
foo  (Account (Code c, Name n)) = "Code " ++ c ++ ", Name " ++ n
```

Using a `data` is usually better.

```
data Account = Account Code Name
-- ...
case an of
  Account (Code c) (Name n) -> "Code " ++ c ++ ", Name " ++ n
```